# Getting error while accessing salesforce NPSP setting tab

Tags: salesforce, crm

We have been using salesforce NPSP package but while clicking on the tab "NPSP setting" I am getting error "Collection size 5,627 exceeds maximum size of 1,000."
please help me in finding what is the best way to resolve this issue .
Thanks !!!!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely there is a visualforce page which is performing a query which is returning more than 1000 results which it being used in the VF page.  If this is a managed package contact the provider.  If you have access to the code you should consider using the standardSetController or implement pagination on the query results, or add additional filters to the query, to limit how many results are returned to the VF page.